# Jquery to take value inside function onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

**This little script to take values from select**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
var clv1=jQuery("#tr_val").val();
});
</script>
```

When click over this div and execute function open_win, i need send value of select inside function **jQuery("#tr_val").val();**

```
<div onclick="open_win(""+clv1,'test');">Test</div>
```

The problem it´s i don´t know how writte right syntax for insert value **"clv1"** inside function **open_win** when click over div Test

I have only this problem, i try different combinations but no works me never

**Thank´s in advanced**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable, and on change of your select you can modified that variable.

While on div element you can add id, and write event handler into script tag(here you can access that global variable).

Note: However global variable are not the correct way, but you can do it for learning/testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for, I've re-organised things a little. There is now a custom function that you call from the inline `onclick` of the `div`. Rather than trying to grab the value on document ready you can do it with the click, I think this simplifies the process.

Let me know if this isn't what you were hoping for.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add a function which you call from the inline onclick
function open_win() {

  // Gather the value of the input
  console.log( $("#tr_val").val() );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="tr_val" value="one">

<div onclick="open_win()">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this, store the value on the `div`'s `data` attribute and then access it inside the function.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function open_win(){
  $(this).data("val", $("#tr_val").val());
  console.log($(this).data('val'));
}
</script>
<div onclick="open_win()">Test</div>
<select id="tr_val">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

**Note:** your `open_win` function must be defined before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 ways

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<input id="tr_val" value="element value" hidden>

<div class="open-div" data-text='test'>Test</div>
```

```
(function ($) {

  $(function () {
    let tr_val = $('#tr_val').val();

    $('.open-div').on('click', function (e) {
      let $this = $(this);
      let text = $this.data("text");

      console.log(tr_val);
      console.log(text);
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

https://codepen.io/nsivanoly/pen/OemWNM

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the value of the element with the id `tr_val` when you click on the div try something like this. put the click event in the javascript as well. Also if you want to run a function like you're trying to do inline you need to have that function defined, but can also use it in the script tags/js file

```
function open_win(someArg) {
  // do something
}

<div class="test-class">Test</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var clv1 = $("#tr_val").val();

  // anonymous function
  $('.test-class').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(clv1);
  })

  // named function with a parameter
  $('.test-class').on('click', function(e) {
    open_win(clv1);
  })

  // if you wanted named function with parameter to look a bit cleaner
  // using es6 arrow function
  $('.test-class').on('click', (e) => open_win(clv1))

  // name function no param (event is the first argument passed in by default but you can't pass params in like this)
 $('.test-class').on('click', open_win)
});
</script>
```